# C pointers and || operators

Tags: c, pointers, casting, logical-operators

I'm just wondering whether this is "good" code for a C89 program.

```
obj_ptr = (obj*) (ptr1 || ptr2);
```

Essentially what it does (atleast in GCC on my computer) is set obj_ptr as ptr1 if ptr1 != NULL and ptr2 otherwise.

I've looked around and I can't see whether this is proper, but judging by the fact that the || operator has to convert the pointers to integers and then I have to cast them back is a hint of bad style.

If this is bad style or unportable, and is there a better and (hopefully) equally as terse solution?

EDIT: My primary concern whether the code I have written is portable and doesn't rely on undefined behavior.

I may have found a better way which is portable and which I think is "good style" (unless you don't like assignment in if statements).

```
if(!(obj_ptr = ptr1))
    obj_ptr = ptr2;
```

Comment: Don't look for terse.  That's so 70's.  Look for clear and understandable (read: maintainable).

Comment: It's not only non-portable, it's just plain wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong. I need to stop hacking and write some good code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, what it does is set `obj_ptr` to `1` if either `ptr1` is not NULL or `ptr2` is not NULL, and `0` otherwise. You need to use the ternary operator:

```
obj_ptr = ptr1 ? ptr1 : ptr2;
```

Comment: I don't think so. When I compile it on my computer it doesn't convert the results to 1. I think the reason this is is that in C true is defined as any number that is not 0.

Comment: @Tnelsond: Print the value with `%p`, I'd be surprised if you don't get `0x1`.

Comment: But the result of `a|| b` should be zero if both `a` and `b` are zero, or otherwise 1.  You might be using a buggy compiler.

Comment: So you're saying that what the result is if they both aren't NULL is undefined behavior?

Comment: The result of the || operator is not a pointer.  It's horrible code.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie, sorry I was getting a bit confused with all the different answers.

Comment: @Carey yeah I think some people are confused with other languages like lua where you can do `a = b or c` and it will set `a` to the first one that doesn't evaluate to `false`, or the second one.

Comment: I guess my other code that I wrote was always giving me 0 so I didn't notice that when it wasn't it was yielding 1, thanks everybody.

Comment: I've been bitten by this before. This is the best solution.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it would definitely be invalid in C++ (where both operands are promoted to `bool`).  I admit I am not sure about C.

[Update]  OK, found it, C99 spec section 6.5.14:

> **Semantics**
>
> The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands
>   compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

So `||` always evaluates either to 0 or to 1.

The usual way to formulate that expression is:

```
obj_ptr = (ptr1 ? ptr1 : ptr2);
```

If you actually need the (obj *) cast, there is a good chance you are doing something wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't need the cast in this case

Comment: @David:  I figured it was being included for a good reason, but you are right, it is probably being included for a bad reason :-)

Comment: The cast was neccessary with my code, my compiler complained, but I guess I was doing integer logic with pointers.

Comment: @Nemo: I really like the ternary operator, but I don't like how I have to write ptr1 twice in this case.

Comment: +1 for "If you actually need the (obj *) cast, there is a good chance you are doing something wrong."

Comment: @Tnelsond: GCC has an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) that lets you write `ptr1 ? : ptr2`, but it is just that:  A non-standard extension.  You can also use an if-else sequence, of course.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't like writing ptr1 twice, you can use a macro:

```
#define or(a, b) (a ? a : b)

obj_ptr = or(ptr1, prt2);
```

Comment: That kind of macro is an absolute abuse of macros.  It's reinventing the language and hiding what's actually happening.  It's the most unmaintainable nonsense possible.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but if "a" is a function call that'd suffer unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Never mind unnecessary overhead.  Once you've had to deal with 50K+ lines of code where people concealed the obvious with cute macros like this, you'll understand how evil they are.

Comment: @Amardeep: Can you find the question about "words you invented?" and add yours? I love it.

Comment: :) I actually agree @carey-gregory.  Since I wouldn't use it myself, I shouldn't have posted it.  I would delete the answer, but that seems like poor form.

Comment: @R.. Thanks.  Actually I posted it in that question last year.  I believe that question has since been closed by a moderator.